# Capitalization of acronyms - maybe there is no definite correctness for all cases?

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

Is it correct to capitalize the acronym when it is a name? Sometimes it is dubious whether it's a name or a word, for example SQL, ANSI, GNU and more would be considered a name so it should be capitalized, while RAM (random access memory) is a word not reserved as a name. I'm not sure about some of them on my list, for example FPGA could be considered both a name and an ordinary word.

```
Acronyms
ACL2 A Computational Logic for Applicative Common Lisp
ANSI American National Standards Institute
ASLR address space layout randomization
CPU central processing unit
DDC diverse double-compiling
DoS denial of service
FPGA field-programmable gate array
GCC GNU Compiler Collection ... <code follows>

\acro{ACL2}{A Computational Logic for Applicative Common Lisp}
\acro{ANSI}{American National Standards Institute}
\acro{ASLR}{address space layout randomization}
\acro{BTC}{Bitcoin Core}
\acro{CDG}{control dependency graph}
\acro{CFG}{control flow graph}
\acro{CPU}{central processing unit}
\acro{CVE}{Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures}
\acro{CVSS}{common vulnerability scoring system}
\acro{CWE}{common weakness enumeration}
\acro{DAST}{dynamic application security testing}
\acro{DDC}{diverse double-compiling}
\acro{DDG}{data dependency graph}
\acro{DeFi}{decentralized finance}
\acro{DoS}{denial of service}
\acro{ELF}{Executable and Linkable Format}
\acro{FPGA}{field-programmable gate array}
\acrodefplural{FPGA}{field-programmable gate arrays}
\acro{GCC}{GNU Compiler Collection}
\acro{GDB}{GNU Debugger}
\acro{HDL}{hardware description language}
\acro{HT}{hardware trojan}
\acro{LISP}{List Processing Language}
\acro{MIPS}{Microprocessor without Interlocked Pipeline Stages}
\acro{ML}{Meta Language}
\acro{MNC}{multinational corporation}
\acrodefplural{MNC}{multinational corporations}
\acro{MULTICS}{Multiplexed Information and Computing Service}
\acro{MiTM}{man-in-the-middle}
\acro{NFT}{non-fungible token}
\acrodefplural{NFT}{non-fungible tokens}
\acro{NGO}{non-government organization}
\acro{NIST}{National Institute for Standardization}
\acro{NIST}{National institute of Standards and Technology}
\acro{OSS}{open source software}
\acro{PDG}{program dependency graph}
\acro{PGP}{Pretty Good Privacy}
\acro{PoLP}{principle of least privilege}
\acro{RAM}{random access memory}
\acro{RCA}{response-computable authentication}
\acro{RoTT}{Reflections on Trusting Trust}
\acro{SAST}{static application security testing}
\acro{SDLC}{software development lifecycle}
\acro{SL}{source language}
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{TCC}{Tiny C Compiler}
\acro{TL}{target language}
\acro{VCS}{version control system}
\acro{VHDL}{VHSIC hardware description language}
\acro{VM}{virtual machine}
\acro{XBI}{cross-build injection}
\acro{YAML}{YAML Ain't Markup Language}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a rule. Most are capitalised, but not all are. And some e.g. Nato/NATO there seems to be a dispute. Consult style guides, dictionaries, Wikipedia, etc, in individual cases. See e.g. [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51924)

Comment: However the example RAM which is also a word with another meaning is always capitalised as an acronym. It's not very clear what the actual question is.

Comment: Please see the discussions at [Does pronouncing an initialism make it an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87381/does-pronouncing-an-initialism-make-it-an-acronym) and [VTOL_ hybrid initialism/acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591409/vtol-hybrid-initialism-acronym) for clarification (or not) of terminology.

Comment: I apologize for what might be a miscommunication from me. I meant to ask if the acronym, when written out, should be capitalized: We use Field-Programmable Gate Arrays (FPGAs) _OR_ We use field-programmable gate-arrays (FPGA). \acro{FPGA}{field-programmable gate array}

Answer (score 2):

Initialisms or acronyms *always* have capitals, or they will be read as ordinary words. Some sentences will have very different meanings:

> My ram is fritzed.
> My RAM is fritzed.

Some will be unintelligible without the indication which capitals afford:

> We will use dast in this case.

Some can't be pronounced as words at all.

> He works for an NGO abroad.

Now, some acronyms which can be pronounced as words have become so well-known that they are accepted as words in their own right. It would be unusual to use capitals (or even small capitals) for these.

> Pick up your scuba gear over there.
> The laser-guided nylon missile was detected using radar.

But until the thing referred to has become common enough that a **word** is needed for it, and its initialism can be pronounced and function as a word, it will always have capitals.

For things like ANSI and NATO etc, where the word is pronounceable but actually represents a proper name where all the constituent words would have a capital, I would expect capitals to be used; but as others have [commented](/q/595684#comment1498443_595684), *Nato* is becoming common (although it still has an initial capital) and at least one UK newspaper refers to police constables as *Pc* rather than *PC.* The use of lower-case letters may be due to the appearance on the page being affected by all-caps, with small-caps (ɴᴀᴛᴏ, ᴘᴄ) being difficult to achieve.

Wikipedia has a [very comprehensive article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) for further reading.