# Term for a word based on an initialism

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics, acronyms, neologisms, initialisms

I recently came across the word 'geeb', a pronunciation and "wordification" of 'GB', itself an initialism of 'gravity bong'. It reminded me of 'okay', which has a similar relationship with 'OK', an ititialism of 'Oll Korrect'.

I was wondering if there was a term for a word that is formed from the pronunciation of the letters in an initialism? Or if there's a term for that process?

Note: this is distinct from an acronym in that an acronym is the pronunciation of letters as a word, whereas I'm asking about pronouncing the names of letters as a word (e.g. 'NASA' as /næ.sə/ vs /ɛn.ɛɪ.ɛs.ɛɪ/).

Comment: See [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87381/does-pronouncing-an-initialism-make-it-an-acronym?rq=1).

Comment: There probably aren't enough to have prompted the feeling that a term is needed.

Comment: There's a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591409/vtol-hybrid-initialism-acronym) on hybrids like JPEG, VTOL, HVAC which don't seem to have a distinct term. Also shortened versions like "Beeb" /bi:b/ for BBC. The OED has an entry on Beeb which says "Formed within English, by clipping or shortening. Etymon: B.B.C. n. Representing a contraction of B.B.C. n. (the British Broadcasting Corporation)."

Comment: Veepee and deejay are a couple more.

Comment: *GB* would be pronounced *jeebee* — not *jeeb*.

Comment: "Jeep" is an oldie, it comes from GP, for General Purpose vehicle.

Comment: @PhilSweet A better example would be "Veep", a common shortening of Veepee (as in the TV show title).